# Segmentation Fault (core dumped) infinite recursion

Tags: c++

I am getting a segmentation fault when I run my program.Someone had mentioned to me that there was some code that would cause an infinite loop and crash the program, which I assume is what is happening. However they did not tell me the part of the code that was doing this, so this is just a guess. Also, as an aside, can someone tell me if the return statements are necessary when I overload the "<<" and ">>" operators? After compiling with g++ -Wall, it warned me that there was no return statement in the function that was not of type void.

I will provide the source code from the three files I am using:

main.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include "my_int.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    my_int value1;
    my_int value2(5);

    // testing the constructors

    cout <<" Value 1 contains "<<value1 <<endl <<endl;
    cout <<" Value 2 contains "<<value2 <<endl <<endl;

    // testing the extraction and insertion operators
    cout <<"Enter an int value -- >  ";
    cin >> value1;
    cout <<"Value1 now contains "<<value1<<endl<<endl;

    // testing binary operators

    cout << value1 << " + " << value2 << " = " << value1 + value2 <<endl <<endl;
    cout << value1 << " - " << value2 << " = " << value1 - value2 <<endl <<endl;
    cout << value1 << " * " << value2  << " = " << value1 * value2  <<endl <<endl;
    cout << value1 << " / " << value2 << " = " << value1 / value2 <<endl <<endl;

    cout << value1 << " * " << 3  << " = " << value1 * 3  <<endl <<endl;

    // testing the % operator

    if (value1 % 2 == 0)
        cout << value1 << " is even  \n\n";
    else
        cout << value1 << " is odd \n\n";

    // testing comparison operators

    if (value1 <= value2)
        cout<<value1 << " <= "<< value2 <<endl;
    else
        cout<<value1 << " > "<< value2 <<endl;

    if (value1 == value2)
       cout<<value1 << " == "<< value2 <<endl;
    else
       cout<<value1 << " != "<< value2 <<endl;

    // testing increment and decrement operators

    ++value1;
    cout <<" increment the value1 by 1 "<< value1 << endl;

    --value2;
    cout <<" decrement the value2 by 1 "<< value2 << endl;

    // testing the set function

    value1.set(25);

    cout <<" Value1 now contains  "<< value1 <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

my_int.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include "my_int.h"
using namespace std;

my_int::my_int(int x){
    val = x;
}

my_int::my_int(){
    val = 0;
}

void my_int::set(int num){
    val = num;
}

my_int operator +(const my_int& num1, const my_int& num2){
    my_int temp;
    temp = num1 + num2;
    return(temp);
}

my_int operator -(const my_int& num1, const my_int& num2){
    my_int temp;
    temp = num1 - num2;
    return(temp);
}

my_int operator %(const my_int& num1, int num2){
    my_int temp;
    temp = num1%num2;
    return(temp);
}

my_int operator /(const my_int& num1, const my_int& num2){
    my_int temp;
    temp = num1/num2;
    return(temp);
}

my_int operator *(const my_int& num1, int num2){
    my_int temp;
    temp = num1*num2;
    return(temp);
}

my_int operator *(const my_int& num1, const my_int& num2);

void my_int::operator ++(){
    val += 1;
}

void my_int::operator --(){
    val -= 1;
}

bool operator ==(const my_int& num1, const my_int& num2){
    return(num1 == num2);
}

bool operator <=(const my_int& num1, const my_int& num2){
    return(num1 <= num2);
}

istream& operator >>(istream& inp, my_int& num){
    inp >> num;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream& outp, const my_int& num){
    outp << num;
}

int my_int::get_val()const{
    return(val);
}
```

my_int.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class my_int
{
public:
    //constructors
    my_int(int x);
    my_int();

    // friend functions
    friend my_int operator + (const my_int& num1, const my_int& num2);

    friend my_int operator - (const my_int& num1, const my_int& num2);

    friend my_int operator % (const my_int& num1,  int num2);

    friend my_int operator *(const my_int& num1, const my_int& num2);

    friend bool operator <= (const my_int& num1, const my_int& num2);

    friend istream& operator >> (istream& inp,  my_int& num);

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& outp, const my_int& num);

    //mutators
    void set(int num);
    void operator ++();
    void operator --();

    // accessors
    int get_val()const;

 private:
     int val;
};

// non-member operators

my_int operator * (const my_int& num1, int num2);

my_int operator / (const my_int& num1, const my_int& num2);

bool operator == (const my_int& num1, const my_int& num2);
```

Any help you guys could provide would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can't you please try to reproduce the problem with a shorter piece of code?

Answer (score 2):

All your operators are causing infinite loops:

```
my_int operator +(const my_int& num1, const my_int& num2){

    my_int temp;
    temp = num1 + num2; // this uses operator+(const my_int& num1, const my_int& num2)

    return(temp);

}
```

Must be:

```
my_int operator +(const my_int& num1, const my_int& num2){

    return my_int( num1.val + num2.val); // this uses pre-defined operator+(int num1, int num2)

}
```

Same comment for `-`, `%`, `*`, `==`, ...

For your next development, I would recommend that you write one function, test it, write another, test it and so one. Then you can fix the bugs one by one ;-)

Comment: Ok so basically I was referencing the operator that I had just overloaded, so when the + came about it went back to the beginning  of the definition?

Comment: operator+ called operator+ who called operator+ who called operator+ untill the stack was full! That's an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

In this functions you forgot to return a value:

```
istream& operator >>(istream& inp, my_int& num){
    inp >> num;
    return inp; //You forgot this line
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream& outp, const my_int& num){
    outp << num;
    return outp; //and this one
}
```

Next, there is missing an implementation of the following function:

```
my_int operator *(const my_int& num1, const my_int& num2);
```

And your operators `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and `%` are causing infinite loop. You need to increment a value and not call your operator again...